# how do i create a simple semantic web page

Tags: semantic-web, protege4

i have created ontologies using protege 4.0 alpha .I want to use that created ontologies and create a semantic web page displaying the ontologies created.
I have read semantic web programming by john heber but its not giving a clear view how to create a semantic web page using ontology.

Comment: What do you mean by “a semantic web page”?  I don't know of a standard definition of such a term, and I could see it being used to describe “an XHTML page with RDFa content“, an RDF document containing some instance data (a page in the Semantic Web), or something else entirely.  Can you be more specific about what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Your `.owl` file is like a `.xml` file, you use it to store information. Your web browser can open and display the raw content of this type of file.

If you want to do a more complex rendering using HTML, then you have to parse the file and generate the web pages from it, like you would do for XML or any type, flat file or databases. You can use the [OWL-API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/) or [Jena](http://jena.apache.org/) to parse and manipulate the OWL file.

If what you want is to enrich your web pages with semantic information for search engines, you can look at [schema.org](http://schema.org/).